# How to serve a defined path with Meteor?

Tags: path, meteor

Currently I'm connecting to my meteor project using `http://localhost:3000` which uses my meteorApp.html file.

How could I make Meteor respond to the following url:
`http://localhost:3000/otherPath` ?

To be more explicit, I do have a file on the server side I just would like to be able to retrieve on the client side using `http://localhost:3000/nameOfTheFile.sufix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just put `nameOfTheFile.sufix` under `public` directory.

See http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Comment: Then /public/someFile.html will be accessible from http://localhost:3000/someFile.html ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want otherPath to be within meteor app, public won't do.
There are several ways to do that, http://multi-page-config.meteor.com is one way to create what looks like a traditional multipage site within one meteor process.

I did this a while ago and have since perfected it a bit but haven't updated it.. this at least might give you some ideas... you can look at the source here: https://github.com/bolora/multi-page-config